# Error when getting value form registry in magento2

Tags: magento2, ui

I have follow [link to get registry](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html)

It's working fine when i getting value of normal input filed but it's throwing error when i am apply for image or wysiwyg component:

form.xml

```
            <field name="default_image">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Ktpl_BannerManagement/form/element/defaultTemplate</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
      <!--        <field name="content" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                            <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataScope>content</dataScope>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <wysiwyg>
                        <settings>
                            <rows>8</rows>
                            <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                        </settings>
                    </wysiwyg>
                </formElements>
            </field> -->
            <field formElement="imageUploader" name="image">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                  <settings>
                    <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
                    <dataType>string</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Upload File</label>
                    <visible>true</visible>
                    <required>false</required>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <imageUploader>
                        <settings>
                            <required>false</required>
                            <uploaderConfig>
                                <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="bannermanagement/image/save"/>
                            </uploaderConfig>
                            <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png ico apng avi MTS M2TS mov qt wmv mp4</allowedExtensions>
                            <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                        </settings>
                    </imageUploader>
                </formElements>
            </field>
```

element.js

```
        var field1 = uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_template');
        var field2 = uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_image');

        var field4 = uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.image');
```

i am getting value of field1 and field1 but not field4.

field4 giving me undefined

Comment: please debug with banner_form.areas.general in log. you get exact result

Comment: which log are you talking about? @AnasMansuri